# How to add increment indicator to a Javascript slider?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, slider

I am currently using the Angular-Slider written by Prajwalkman **[HERE](https://github.com/prajwalkman/angular-slider)**

However I need to add indicators with valid values, I have designed a proof of concept which you can see below. Ideally the values for these indicators will come from an array which will be on the scope.

Current version:

[image]

What I want to achieve: 
[image]

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a library that does just that:

https://www.npmjs.org/package/ng-slider